# The warpwallet challenge 2

Tags: mining-hardware, hash, gpu, brain-wallet

[here](https://keybase.io/warp/warp_1.0.9_SHA256_a2067491ab582bde779f4505055807c2479354633a2216b22cf1e92d1a6e4a87.html)  you can find a public challenge aimed to brute force a brain wallet private key, derived from 8 char long [a-zA-Z0-9] passphrase with a salt of "a@b.c". Is it possible to adapt an hashing hardware to solve this? (Such as GPU)

Answer (score 2):

Yes its doable, but you'd have to write your own custom implementation for scrypt and pbkdf2 hashing as warp wallet uses these 2 algorithms. If you can find a brute force tool for scrypt and pbkdf2 separately, you'd have to combine them somehow. Regardless, you'd have to code this up custom. That 20 BTC reward is worth 80k usd today.

Comment: Thanks,found this: https://github.com/nachowski/warpwallet_cracker but l cannot figure out how to make it runnable on a GPU, maybe vanitygen could be a better starting point?

Comment: @cesko80 A nice starting project if you wanted to customise some software to do what you wanted. vanitygen wouldn't help.

Comment: A software that would be efficient would run on GPU, hence it needs to be coded in OpenCL. BTW, the reward is expired.